# Why Does Wicket Websocket Sometimes Refuse To Send a Message Back To The Server?

Tags: java, websocket, wicket

I've recently encountered this on a project using Apache Wicket 8.6 (it also happened with 7.15).  A Websocket client successfully registers with the backend server application and then refuses to send a message when a dedicated button is clicked.

The HTML (from HomePage.html) is:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="Wicket.WebSocket.send('connect');">CONNECT</button>
    <button onclick="Wicket.WebSocket.send('reset');">RESET</button>
</div>
```

The Java (from HomePage.java) is:

```
add(new WebSocketBehavior() {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   protected void onConnect(ConnectedMessage message) {

       super.onConnect(message);
       logger.log(Level.INFO, "onConnect() message is " + message.toString());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMessage(WebSocketRequestHandler handler, TextMessage message) {

       logger.info("Got message " + message.getText() + " from browser.");
   }
}
```

In the browser debugger I can see the button event as the button is being clicked, but it's as if the message simply isn't being sent.  What's worse is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, so I can't reproduce it consistently but since it happens in both Firefox 69.0 and Vivaldi 2.8.1664.38, I can only assume it's something that neither browser likes.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I'd recommend you to put a breakpoint at send() method and see what is the problem: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/5d0b0b68549a5709094f0d8f20f6f0e558e4f251/wicket-native-websocket/wicket-native-websocket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/ws/api/res/js/wicket-websocket-jquery.js#L135. Otherwise please create a mini application that reproduces it (sometimes) and we can take a look.

Comment: I got pulled away from this, but recently managed to get time to take another look at it. From my observations using the debugger, it would appear that when the page is first loaded, the WebSocket communication isn't actually set up.  Hitting refresh in the browser not only reloads the page, but also then sets up the WebSocket communication.  For what it's worth, I'm using Tomcat 9.0.24 with the JavaxWebSocketFilter.

Comment: Additionally, the refresh technique only works in Firefox.  It has no effect in Vivaldi (which I assume applies to most if not all Chrome-based browsers).

Comment: Please create a mini app that reproduces the problem and share it with us to take a look.